# Get status of a deployment programmatically

Tags: api, deployment

I want to get the status from the last deployment in an apex class. I find [this API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_checkdeploystatus.htm) but the problem is, I don't know how to get the id of the deployment in progress / last deployment finished.

Is there a way to get this Id programmatically?